# How to remove '/' in the JSON array and to get particular value from JSON array?

Tags: json, object

I have this below JSON array how to remove '\' in the keys and values.
[{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW1\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW1\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 1\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person1\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW2\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW2\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 2\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person2\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW3\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW3\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 3\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person3\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW4\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW4\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 4\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person4\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW5\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW5\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 5\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person5\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}]

Comment: Find & replace?

Comment: what have you tried? what environment are you using?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: @MisaelMoneróThompson I am using Javascript

Answer (score 0):

That's not JSON. This code can convert the string to list.

```
# this is javascript code.
a = '[{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW1\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW1\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 1\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person1\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW2\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW2\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 2\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person2\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW3\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW3\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 3\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person3\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW4\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW4\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 4\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person4\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW5\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW5\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 5\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person5\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}]'

b = a.replace(/\",\"/g,",")
ret = JSON.parse(b)

# the ret is answer.
```

```
# python code.
import json, ast
# first, you have to add '' at your json data start and end.
a = '[{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW1\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW1\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 1\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person1\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW2\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW2\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 2\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person2\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW3\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW3\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 3\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person3\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW4\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW4\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 4\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person4\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}","{\"docType\":\"wallet\"","\"id\":\"DW5\"","\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW5\"","\"name\":\"benefactor 5\"","\"objType\":\"benefactor\"","\"personId\":\"person5\"","\"reference\":\"\"","\"status\":1","\"totalDonated\":0","\"water\":0}]'
m = a.replace('\\\"', '\"').replace("\",\"", ",")
m = ast.literal_eval(m)
print(m, type(m))
print(json.dumps(m))
```

```
output:
([{'status': 1, 'totalDonated': 0, 'name': 'benefactor 1', 'reference': '', 'personId': 'person1', 'docType': 'wallet', 'water': 0, 'objType': 'benefactor', 'id': 'DW1', 'identity': 'wallet:benefactor:DW1'}, {'status': 1, 'totalDonated': 0, 'name': 'benefactor 2', 'reference': '', 'personId': 'person2', 'docType': 'wallet', 'water': 0, 'objType': 'benefactor', 'id': 'DW2', 'identity': 'wallet:benefactor:DW2'}, {'status': 1, 'totalDonated': 0, 'name': 'benefactor 3', 'reference': '', 'personId': 'person3', 'docType': 'wallet', 'water': 0, 'objType': 'benefactor', 'id': 'DW3', 'identity': 'wallet:benefactor:DW3'}, {'status': 1, 'totalDonated': 0, 'name': 'benefactor 4', 'reference': '', 'personId': 'person4', 'docType': 'wallet', 'water': 0, 'objType': 'benefactor', 'id': 'DW4', 'identity': 'wallet:benefactor:DW4'}, {'status': 1, 'totalDonated': 0, 'name': 'benefactor 5', 'reference': '', 'personId': 'person5', 'docType': 'wallet', 'water': 0, 'objType': 'benefactor', 'id': 'DW5', 'identity': 'wallet:benefactor:DW5'}], <type 'list'>)
[{"status": 1, "totalDonated": 0, "name": "benefactor 1", "reference": "", "personId": "person1", "docType": "wallet", "water": 0, "objType": "benefactor", "id": "DW1", "identity": "wallet:benefactor:DW1"}, {"status": 1, "totalDonated": 0, "name": "benefactor 2", "reference": "", "personId": "person2", "docType": "wallet", "water": 0, "objType": "benefactor", "id": "DW2", "identity": "wallet:benefactor:DW2"}, {"status": 1, "totalDonated": 0, "name": "benefactor 3", "reference": "", "personId": "person3", "docType": "wallet", "water": 0, "objType": "benefactor", "id": "DW3", "identity": "wallet:benefactor:DW3"}, {"status": 1, "totalDonated": 0, "name": "benefactor 4", "reference": "", "personId": "person4", "docType": "wallet", "water": 0, "objType": "benefactor", "id": "DW4", "identity": "wallet:benefactor:DW4"}, {"status": 1, "totalDonated": 0, "name": "benefactor 5", "reference": "", "personId": "person5", "docType": "wallet", "water": 0, "objType": "benefactor", "id": "DW5", "identity": "wallet:benefactor:DW5"}]


# the below print from Python interpreter 
# Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
print(json.dumps(m))
"[{\"docType\":\"wallet\",\"id\":\"DW1\",\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW1\",\"name\":\"benefactor 1\",\"objType\":\"benefactor\",\"personId\":\"person1\",\"reference\":\"\",\"status\":1,\"totalDonated\":0,\"water\":0},{\"docType\":\"wallet\",\"id\":\"DW2\",\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW2\",\"name\":\"benefactor 2\",\"objType\":\"benefactor\",\"personId\":\"person2\",\"reference\":\"\",\"status\":1,\"totalDonated\":0,\"water\":0},{\"docType\":\"wallet\",\"id\":\"DW3\",\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW3\",\"name\":\"benefactor 3\",\"objType\":\"benefactor\",\"personId\":\"person3\",\"reference\":\"\",\"status\":1,\"totalDonated\":0,\"water\":0},{\"docType\":\"wallet\",\"id\":\"DW4\",\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW4\",\"name\":\"benefactor 4\",\"objType\":\"benefactor\",\"personId\":\"person4\",\"reference\":\"\",\"status\":1,\"totalDonated\":0,\"water\":0},{\"docType\":\"wallet\",\"id\":\"DW5\",\"identity\":\"wallet:benefactor:DW5\",\"name\":\"benefactor 5\",\"objType\":\"benefactor\",\"personId\":\"person5\",\"reference\":\"\",\"status\":1,\"totalDonated\":0,\"water\":0}]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea how can i convert it in javascript.

Comment: OK，I update the answer. and on the top code is convert it in javascript @OmkarSaiSunku

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help! Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you @OmkarSaiSunku :)